# Plotting pandas data frame in time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame which contains errors in an application by day:

```html
date         code         server                 type
2017-06-20 ADFC-64001 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64001 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64003 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64003 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64002 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64001 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64003 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64003 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64002 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
2017-06-20 ADFC-64001 nexteesadf_server1 WARNING
```

I would now like to plot the # occurrences of each error per day as a line chart in time. So there will be 1 line for ADFC-64001, 1 line for ADFC-64002 and so on over the time period.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.groupby('code').resample('D').count().type.unstack('date').fillna(0))

date        2017-06-20  2017-06-21  2017-06-22  2017-06-23  2017-06-25
code                                                                  
ADFC-64001         4.0         1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
ADFC-64002         2.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0
ADFC-64003         3.0         2.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
```

data

```
          date        code              server     type
0   2017-06-20  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
1   2017-06-20  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
2   2017-06-20  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
3   2017-06-20  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
4   2017-06-20  ADFC-64002  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
5   2017-06-20  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
6   2017-06-20  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
7   2017-06-21  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
8   2017-06-20  ADFC-64002  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
9   2017-06-20  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
10  2017-06-21  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
11  2017-06-21  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
12  2017-06-22  ADFC-64003  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
13  2017-06-23  ADFC-64002  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
14  2017-06-25  ADFC-64001  nexteesadf_server1  WARNING
```

plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
df.groupby('code').resample('D').count().type.unstack('date').fillna(0).T.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this its great - how do I only include the top x errors when plotting?

Comment: @user7289 You can get n-larget index by `idx = df.groupby('code').resample('D').count().type.unstack('date').fillna(0).sum(axis=1).nlargest(2).index` and use it to filter top x errors like `to_plot_df.loc[:, idx]`.